# 2012 Macbook Pro Boots With Startup Sound, But Has Black Screen

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

This is sorta urgent, since my dad's whole business relies on his computer, and it needs to be fixed. 
Anyway, it will startup and and make the mac "on" chime. But after that, nothing happens. We can tell it is on because pressing the caps lock key will turn the capslock light on and off, and the black screen is still brighter than the bezel. We tried doing a PRAM reset, and that didn't work at all. We still have yet to start in Safe Mode, but again, this is my dad's whole business at stake, so if you or you know someone who can help, that would be great.

-LionMac

EDIT: We just tried booting it in safe mode, and nothing happened. (Maybe it is the logic board. If it is, could someone confirm that so we don't waste any more time trying different solutions?)

Comment: Try [this](http://osxdaily.com/2014/11/22/fix-macbook-pro-booting-black-screen/) article

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer, but actually that is an article that we actually just tried, and none of the solutions worked.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone here will be able to figure this out, especially considering your time crunch.  We can offer suggestions but my guess is you've already searched for this problem and tried whatever you found.  I'd recommend just taking it in to Apple, or another repair place you trust, and have them look at it.  That would be the fastest, safest way to getting this fixed.

Comment: Is it booted: once booted, does the sound increase key make your Mac play the usual sound?

Comment: That is a great suggestion. I tried it, and it did not make the chime sound.

Comment: Do you have an external monitor you can try hooking it up to?

Comment: Yes. We tried hooking it up to two thunderbolt monitors, but nothing happened.

Comment: Try this article, maybe: https://www.macissues.com/2015/04/07/tackle-your-mac-booting-to-a-gray-screen/

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I would like someone to close this topic, because our problem is fixed. My dad took it to the Genius Bar at our Local Apple store, and they found out it was a problem with the power supply. (Not sure how that happened, especially considering the symptoms the Mac had) But anyway, thank you for all of your help.